# Database telling whether a product is recyclable or not, by barcode

Tags: data-request, products, barcodes

I'm attempting to create an app that uses barcodes of items to decide whether they are recyclable or not. I am already able to go from the barcode to the item, but I am unable to find any database or anything linking item names to their material or their recyclability. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Even if the item itself isn't recyclable, the packaging might be.  (eg, food containers).  Other items may be recycled if disassembled, which requires taking them to specialty recyclers, and not a curb-side pickup ... so the response won't just be a simple binary yes/no.